# ONENDED event doesn't work for HTML5 Flash Videos Playing

Tags: jquery, flash, html, video

I want to use the EMBED element to run a flash video. I used JQuery to
integrate it (see code fragment below).

The flash is running but I want to run it just a single time and get informed
if it has ended (with the ONENDED event). Instead it is running always in LOOP mode
and I doi not receive the event.

With the VIDEO element of HTML5 it is working well with mp4 and ogv.

How can I get it running with Flash as well ?

```
flashobj = document.createElement('embed');
flashobj.src = 'flash/bmw_i8_concept.swf';
flashobj.type = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
flashobj.width=500;

flashobj.onended = function(e) {
    alert("flash ended: " + e);
}

$(media_container).append(flashobj);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because Flash movies don't dispatch JavaScript events, unless you configure an [ExternalInterface](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/external_interface.html) method to do so.

It is also not possible to stop a Flash movie from JavaScript, unless the movie explicitly allows script access.  The easiest way to prevent the movie from looping would be to insert a `stop();` statement on the last frame of the Flash movie, if you have access to the source FLA.

Comment: Would the existency of a stop() statement cause the generation of the HTML5 ONENDED event ? Do you know if there is any video converter software on the market which e.g. generates the appropriate statement during e.g. a convertion from mp4 to swf ?

Comment: No on both counts, because an SWF file is not a video - it is an executable binary.  The only way you will get an event into JavaScript is by using ExternalInterface.